# The screens remain off after locking them in Debian

Tags: debian, xfce, screen-lock

I have Debian SO as root and I have installed the XFCE desktop distribution.

After this, it seems that I have lost the keyboard shortcuts and when I lock the screens I do not get the traditional lock screen or the login screen, they remain off, the laptop screen and the monitor screen.

I only have one user.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Greetings.

Comment: please elaborate? does this work for another user, or everything is affected?

Comment: I only have one user

Comment: do you have any shortcuts defined in `/root/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`? Check also this: http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xfce_keyboard_shortcuts.html

Comment: for xfce4 I don´t have any keyboard shortcuts. But the most important problem is the screens, that they still blank after locking.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably [#929834](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=929834). There are two workarounds until the issue is fixed:

- if you type your password in blindly, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the screen should unlock and switch on;
- if you switch VTs, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, the screen should switch on; reverting to your original VT (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>) should then show the unlock prompt.

Comment: I did what you say, but it is not working correctly